# Custom JSS theme overwrites material UI theme?

Tags: reactjs, themes, material-ui, jss

I'm using JSS themes to style my components, but it seems my custom JSS theme overwrites the JSS theme used by the Material UI components. I'm using material-ui 1.0.0-beta.22

It looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react
import injectSheet, {ThemeProvider} from 'react-jss
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog'

const theme = {
  background: 'blue'
}

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    background: theme.background,
  }
})

const Demo = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div className={props.classes.demo}>
      <Dialog />
    </div>
  </ThemeProvider>
)

export default injectSheet(styles)(Demo)
```

When rendering this component, it causes the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unit' of undefined
    at styles (Dialog.js?9662:87)
    at Object.create (getStylesCreator.js?6ed6:29)
    at Style.attach (withStyles.js?deb5:328)
    at Style.componentWillMount (withStyles.js?deb5:258)
    at callComponentWillMount (react-dom.development.js?cada:9777)
    at mountClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?cada:9834)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:10216)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10605)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12573)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?cada:12682)
```

The Material UI Dialog component tries to access props.theme.spacing.unit, but no such property exists, as the whole theme has been overwritten by my custom theme.

Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong? Shouldn't JSS themes at least be merged? Am I missing some Material UI theming config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are using the same provider. If you want a different theming for your react-jss components, you can setup https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss#theming a new namespace for theming, see "createTheming"

Comment: Does this namespace needs to be imported and passed to `injectSheet` in every component using it, i.e. `injectSheet(styles, {customTheming})`?
I'm now getting the following errors in my components:

- Warning: Failed context type: The context `__THEMING__` is marked as required in `Jss(FormDesignerToolbar)`, but its value is `undefined`.
- Uncaught Error: [undefined] Please use ThemeProvider to be able to use WithTheme


I'm importing my namespaced theme and passing it to `injectSheet`

Comment: By changing my import from `import customTheme from '../path/to/custom/theme'` to `import theming from '../path/to/custom/theming'` and `injectSheet(styles, {customTheme})` to `injectSheet(styles, {theming})` (i.e. changing import name from customTheme to **theming**)it now works. But this feels cumbersome - am I doing it wrong, or do I have to import my custom theming object in every component that uses it?